# Independently uniformly distributed density functions U=X/Y

Tags: probability

$f(x)=1,0<x<1$
$f(y)=1,0<y<1 $
Let $U=X/Y$

What is the density function of U?

I have no idea how to solve this kind of questions.

Comment: Find a distribution function of $U$ and then differentiate it, i.e. calculate $P(X/Y\le z)$ and then differentiate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually easier to compute the distribution. $$F_U(u) = P(U\le u) = P(X/Y\le u) = P(X \le u Y)$$

(The last step is only justified because $Y\ge 0$)

Then, think of the event of interest $(X \le u Y)$ in the $X,Y$ plane (make a drawing), find its probability integrating the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ in the region that correspond to that event.